# How to locate the directory of a file for processing in a bash script

Tags: bash

I need help identifying the directory path of a specific file so I can copy an updated version of that file to the same directory. I also need to create a sub directory in the same target directory. The file could exist is multiple directories.

I’ve tried using the following. . .

```
find /.mozilla/firefox -type f -name prefs.js
```

It does work, but it includes the actual file name and full directory and I just need the directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you want the `.mozilla` subdirectory under the root directory? Is this root's firefox preferences you're playing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the directory name with a shell expansion too.

```
file="$(find /.mozilla/firefox -type f -name prefs.js)"

if
  [[ -f "$file" ]]
then
  dir="${file%/*}"
  echo "Directory is : $dir"
else
  echo "File not found"
fi
```

The `"${file%/*}` expansion removes the last slash and everything after from the value of `file`.  It does that by matching the shortest string that begins with a slash, starting from the end of the value of `file`.

Comment: This worked. Only issue was %dir should be $dir on the first echo line.

Comment: @user3151788  Fixed

Answer (score 1):

Use find's `-printf` directive:

```
find /.mozilla/firefox -type f -name prefs.js -printf "%h\n"
```

Comment: `%s` is the size, `%h` is the dirname

Comment: Thank you. Brain fart. I even read the man page to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

You want `find` to additionally run your results through `dirname`:

```
find /.mozilla/firefox -type f -name prefs.js -exec dirname {} \;
```

The `{} \;` is a "magic" string indicating a token for the found name(s) and a delimiter, which has to be escaped so that the shell doesn't see it.

See `man find` for details.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure bash version:

```
shopt -s globstar                     # turn on ** matching
files=(.mozilla/firefox/**/prefs.js)  # find files at any depth
dirs=("${files[@]%/*}")               # remove the ending `/*' portion
```